# Determining if $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$ is a local ring or not

Tags: ring-theory, factoring

I was trying to use the following result which says: if $I$ is a ideal of $R$ such that $R\setminus I$ is the set of all units of $R$ then $I$ is the only maximal ideal of $R$.

I showed that the units of $R$ are $\overline{ aX+1 }$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ but it seems that the complement of the preceding set isn't an ideal. So, it looks to me as if $R$ is not a local ring.

I wasn't able to prove my claim. Can someone drop some hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggestion: instead, look at the map $R\to {\mathbb Z}$, and the inverse image of the primes in the second ring. (This is really the same as Hagen's answer below).

Comment: @peterag It's unfortunate that I cannot see it through. How exactly would I map $R$ to $\mathbb{Z}$? And do you mean prime ideal instead of prime?

Comment: @AshishK in the most obvious way possible: $n+mx + (x^2)\mapsto n$.  It maps onto $\mathbb Z$, with kernel $(x)/(x^2)$.

Comment: Hi Ashish... Exactly as @rschwieb says - and yes, by primes, I meant prime ideals. The point is: if $A$ is a [commutative, say] ring, and $I$ an ideal, the ring homo $A\to A/I$, $a \mapsto a +I$,  gives rise to a bijection (isomorphism on the lattices) between the (set of) ideals of $A/I$ and the (set of) ideals of $A$ containing $I$. For a reference, see the properties section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring

Comment: @peterag ah yes, I'm familiar with the correspondence theorem. Thanks for your response. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any prime $p$, you can readily find a homomorphism $R\to \Bbb F_p$